# No free diskspace warning while using transactional updates

Tags: 16.04, snap

I see the following warnings in Webmin after applying the Ubuntu Snappy transactional updates on my server.

> Warning! The 4.38 MB filesystem mounted at
>   /snap/canonical-livepatch/22 has no free disk space!
>
> Warning! The 78.38 MB filesystem mounted at /snap/core/1441 has no
>   free disk space!
>
> Warning! The 78.38 MB filesystem mounted at /snap/core/1577 has no
>   free disk space!
>
> Warning! The 79.50 MB filesystem mounted at /snap/core/1689 has no
>   free disk space!

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this is just a warning, it can be ignored. However if it's annoying you can suppress it in the webmin theme.

There's a suggestion on [this github issue](https://github.com/qooob/authentic-theme/issues/813).

Which suggests adding the following to the themes extension:-

```
$(function() {
     $('div.alert:contains("filesystem mounted")').remove();
});
```

Comment: Nice workaround... ...But please add the /snap/ into the contains-filter like this: `$('div.alert:contains("filesystem mounted at /snap/")').remove();`. Otherwise it will remove all errors of mounted filesystems.